# Large Varnish VCL does not load

Tags: linux, varnish, access-control-list

I'm using Varnish ACLs for blocking unwanted clients by IP and as the blocklist/ACL has grown the compile time of the VCL has increased a lot. The other day I added another 25K IPs to block and Varnish no longer loads the VCL but instead responds with:

> "Command failed with error code 400" "CLI communication error (hdr)".

Does anyone know of a way of using Varnish to block lots of IP addresses?

I don't want to use iptables as I want to respond with a `403 error` page.

The blocklist ACLs right now contains about 190K entries, most of which are single IPs (i.e. /32, not ranges).

```
/usr/bin/varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6081 vcl.load file_default.vcl_time_1542634958 /etc/varnish/default.vcl
Command failed with error code 400
CLI communication error (hdr)

real    33m20.101s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

The code and the compile step seem to work as compile without load does not throw an error.

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

real    34m50.554s
user    34m33.124s
sys 0m15.332s
```

Comment: Why not use a firewall (e.g. iptables)?

Comment: @CraigWatson I do not want to use iptables as I want to respond with a 403 error page

Comment: I would recommend that you run an additional webservice on different port that will only display your user-friendly error message and nothing else. Then use `ipset` / `iptables` to redirect web request from your unwanted clients to that different port. `ipset`  with `hash:ip` will probably scale better than managing such a large ACL in varnish.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a genuine bug to me: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/3542

Answer (score 0):

Increasing `cli_buffer` (size of buffer for CLI command input; default 8KB) and/or `cli_limit` (maximum  size of CLI response; default 128KB) parameters will probably fix that issue.

Comment: I don't see why that would help. The only thing that has changed is one ACL in the VCL and the full VCL is about 10Mb. Why would it be limited by the cli limits?

Comment: My suggestion is based on past experiences with large VCLs (not because of large ACLs, but because of large synthetic contents) and `varnishadm` + `vcl.inline` / `vcl.show`. Symptoms are identical to the ones described in your question, but I assume you have increased the suggested parameters and it didn't work for you. Sorry!